# Stop a running Docker container by sending SIGTERM

Tags: docker

I have a very very simple Go app listening on port 8080

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(200)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text-plain")
    w.Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.DefaultServeMux))
```

I install it in a Docker container and start it like so:

```
FROM golang:alpine
ADD . /go/src/github.com/myuser/myapp
RUN go install github.com/myuser/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I then run the container using `docker run`:

```
docker run --publish 8080:8080 first-app
```

I expect that, like most programs, I can send a SIGTERM to the process running `docker run` and this will cause the container to stop running. I observe that sending SIGTERM has no effect, and instead I need to use a command like `docker kill` or `docker stop`.

Is this intended behavior? I've asked [in the forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-cannot-be-killed-with-ctrl-c/13108) and on IRC and gotten no answer.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not 100% sure, although I do seem to recall that sending SIGTERM to a process of PID 1 does not actually kill it as you'd expect, because you need to explicitly catch the signal and act on it (see the rationale behind dumb-init for more https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init). Try starting the process via `sh` (specify the entrypoint as a string, not using array syntax) or use `dumb-init` and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about sending a SIGTERM to PID1 in the container. I think he's talking about sending SIGTERM to the pidof docker run on the host?

Comment: @JHarris - I think so too; I just didn't know what sending `docker run` a signal actually did and was taking a stab in the dark. I've just had a look though, and it seems that the `docker run` process proxies all signals through by default ([search this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for `sig-proxy`).

Comment: @JHarris That's correct, sending SIGTERM to the pid of docker run on the host.

Answer (score 23):

Any process executed by `docker run` must handle a signal itself to receive that signal.

Alternatively use the `--init` flag to run the [`tini`](https://github.com/krallin/tini) init as PID 1 which will handle and forward signals for you.

The `sh` shell can also be injected as the PID 1 process in the container, depending on how the command (`CMD`) is specified.

#### Detail

A `SIGTERM` is propagated by the `docker run` command to the Docker daemon by default but it will not take effect unless the signal is specifically handled in main process being run by Docker.

The first process you `run` in a container will have PID 1 in that containers PID namespace. This process is treated as a special process by the linux kernel. It will *not* be sent a signal unless the process has a handler installed for that signal. It is also PID 1's job to forward signals onto other child processes.

`docker run` and other commands are API clients for the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) hosted by the docker daemon. The docker daemon runs as a seperate process and is the parent for the commands you run inside a container context. This means that there is no direct sending of signals between `docker run` and the daemon, in the standard unix manner.

The `docker run` and `docker attach` commands have a `--sig-proxy` flag that defaults signal proxying to `true`. You can turn this off if you want.

`docker exec` [does not proxy signals](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9098).

In a `Dockerfile`, be careful to use the "exec form" when specifying [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) and [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) defaults, if you don't want `sh` to become the PID 1 process ([Kevin Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517806/1318694)):

```
CMD [ "/path/executable", "param1", "param2" ]
```

### Signal Handling Go Example

Using the sample Go code here: https://gobyexample.com/signals

Run a regular process that doesn't handle signals in the background. Then the example Go daemon that traps signals also in the background. I'm using `sleep` for the process that doesn't install "daemon" signal handlers.

```
$ docker run busybox sleep 6000 &
$ docker run gosignal &
```

With a `ps` tool that has a "tree" view, you can see the two distinct process trees. One for the `docker run` process under `sshd`. The other for the actual container processes, under `docker daemon`.

```
$ pstree -p
init(1)-+-VBoxService(1287)
        |-docker(1356)---docker-containe(1369)-+-docker-containe(1511)---gitlab-ci-multi(1520)
        |                                      |-docker-containe(4069)---sleep(4078)
        |                                      `-docker-containe(4638)---main(4649)
        `-sshd(1307)---sshd(1565)---sshd(1567)---sh(1568)-+-docker(4060)
                                                          |-docker(4632)
                                                          `-pstree(4671)
```

The details of docker hosts processes:

```
$ ps -ef | grep "docker r\|sleep\|main"
docker    4060  1568  0 02:57 pts/0    00:00:00 docker run busybox sleep 6000
root      4078  4069  0 02:58 ?        00:00:00 sleep 6000
docker    4632  1568  0 03:10 pts/0    00:00:00 docker run gosignal
root      4649  4638  0 03:10 ?        00:00:00 /main
```

#### Killing

I can't kill the `docker run busybox sleep` command:

```
$ kill 4060
$ ps -ef | grep 4060
docker    4060  1568  0 02:57 pts/0    00:00:00 docker run busybox sleep 6000
```

I can kill the `docker run gosignal` command, that has launched the go process with the signal handlers:

```
$ kill 4632
$ 
terminated
exiting

[2]+  Done                       docker run gosignal
```

#### Signals via `docker exec`

If I `docker exec` a new `sleep` process in the already running `sleep` container, I can send an ctrl-c and interrupt the `docker exec` itself, but that doesn't forward to the actual process:

```
$ docker exec 30b6652cfc04 sleep 600
^C
$ docker exec 30b6652cfc04 ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sleep 6000   <- original
   97 root       0:00 sleep 600    <- execed still running
  102 root       0:00 ps -ef
```

Answer (score 5):

So there are two factors at play here:

1) If you specify a string for an entrypoint, like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/myapp
```

Docker runs the script with `/bin/sh -c 'command'`. This intermediate script gets the SIGTERM, but doesn't send it to the running server app.

To avoid the intermediate layer, specify your entrypoint as an array of strings.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"]
```

2) I built the app I was trying to run with the following string:

```
docker build -t first-app .
```

This tagged the container with the name first-app. Unfortunately when I tried to rebuild/rerun the container I ran:

```
docker build .
```

Which didn't overwrite the tag, so my changes weren't being applied.

Once I did both of those things, I was able to kill the process with ctrl+c, and bring down the running container.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the shell form rather than exec form in the Dockerfile! As people have upvoted the other A I've added a note about it.

Answer (score 1):

A very comprehensive description of this problem and the solutions can be found here:
https://vsupalov.com/docker-compose-stop-slow

In my case, my app expects to receive SIGTERM signal for graceful shutdown didn't receive it because the process started by a bash script which called from a dockerfile in this form: ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/script.sh"]

so the script didn't propagate the SIGTERM to the app.
The solution was to use exec from the script run the command that starts the app: 
e.g. exec java -jar ...