# Docker CMD doesn't see installed components

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image using the following docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Update packages 
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APP_NAME testapp
ENV NODE_VERSION 5.10
ENV SERVE_PORT 8080
ENV LIVE_RELOAD_PORT 8888

# Install nvm, node, and angular
RUN (curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash -) \
    && source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && npm install -g angular-cli \
    && ng new $APP_NAME \
    && cd $APP_NAME \
    && npm run postinstall

EXPOSE $SERVE_PORT $LIVE_RELOAD_PORT

WORKDIR $APP_NAME

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "-v"]
```

But I keep getting an error when trying to run it:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'node' not found or does not exist..
```

I know node is being properly installed because if I rebuild the image by commenting out the CMD line from the docker file

```
#CMD ["node", "-v"]
```

And then start a shell session

```
docker run -it testimage
```

I can see that all my dependencies are there and return proper results

```
node -v
v5.10.1
```

.....

```
ng -v
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.5
node: 5.10.1
os: linux x64
```

So my question is.  Why is the CMD in Dockerfile not able to run these and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the shell to `RUN` `node` via nvm, you have sourced the `nvm.sh` file and it will have a `$PATH` variable set in it's environment to search for executable files via nvm.

When you run commands via `docker run` it will only [inject a default PATH](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

```
docker run <your-ubuntu-image> echo $PATH
docker run <your-ubuntu-image> which node
docker run <your-ubuntu-image> nvm which node
```

Specifying a [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) with an array execs a binary directly without a shell or a `$PATH` to lookup.

Provide the full path to your `node` binary.

```
CMD ["/bin/node","-v"]
```

It's better to use the node binary rather than the `nvm` helper scripts due to the way [dockers signal processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517309/1318694) works. It might be easier to use the [node apt packages](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb) in docker rather than nvm.