# How to kill a docker container created by `spawn` in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am using `child_process.spawn` to launch a docker container as below:

```
const docker = spawn('docker', ['run', '-it', '--rm', 'DOCKER_IMAGE', 'bash'])
```

I wonder how I can stop the process. I tried below method but it doesn't stop the container:

```
docker.kill()
```

it works fine with other regular process command but docker may be different. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve that?

I know the correct way to stop a docker container is to run `docker stop` command. But how I know container ID from the above code?

Answer (score 3):

`<ChildProcess>.kill()` doesn't end the process, it simply sends a signal 'SIGTERM' by default.  So `docker.kill()` sends a 'SIGTERM' to the docker client process which then runs into this issue [Stop a running Docker container by sending SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515686/stop-a-running-docker-container-by-sending-sigterm) short story bash is not init, and will ignore the signal.

You'll need to run a 'docker stop ' command.

Alternatively you can skip shelling out to the docker client and use the docker api directly https://github.com/apocas/dockerode