# Unable to stop my Docker container with Ctrl-C

Tags: docker, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 10 using an Ubuntu image, and Docker for Desktop Windows (2.2.2.0) with the WSL integration.

I have a Rust TCP server. When I run it with `cargo run` (or the binary after `cargo install`), it does the right thing, and I can send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to it to terminate. I don't do any explicit signal handling in the code.

I turned it into a Docker image. Here's the Dockerfile.

```
FROM rust:1.40 as builder
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path . --root .

FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=builder ./bin/myserver ./myserver
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["./myserver"]
```

I then do:

```
docker build -t myserver .
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 myserver
```

Attempting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the process shows the `^C` character in the terminal, but the signal doesn't seem to reach the process. I *have* to use `docker kill`. I've read other posts like [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-cannot-be-killed-with-ctrl-c/13108) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515686/stop-a-running-docker-container-by-sending-sigterm). It suggests that a combination of `-it` and using the array parameter version of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` should allow the signal to reach it, however these don't seem to be helping me.

To see if it was something to do with my setup (Docker for Desktop, WSL, etc.) or my Dockerfile, I followed the README for [docker-http-https-echo](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo), and I'm able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the process. Inspecting the Dockerfile doesn't show that it's doing anything different than me, but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: You may try to add explicit signal handling and log the received signals first.
Then you will know if messages doesn't getting to process or process doesn't handle them well.

Comment: Try to add `--init` flag to `docker run` command, because the Linux kernel applies special signal handling to processes which run as PID 1. Or handle `SIGINT` signal in your app properly.

Comment: It seems it's sort of a combination of your answers and I neglected to properly understand the linked SO answer. The `echo` program I linked _does_ explicitly handle SIGINT, which is why the interrupt worked fine when running that. `--init` does solve my problem here (though maybe not ideally? I don't know if running as PID 1 is bad) , and I'll accept your answer if you post it @Nikscorp.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that the kernel treats a process with PID 1 specially, and does not, by default, kill the process when receiving the `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` signals.

You have two options:

1. Add `--init` flag to `docker run` command. By that a special process with PID 1 will be created, which will be a parent for your process and will proxy all signals and properly reap your processes.
2. Add explicit signal handling to your app, which is good if you want to do graceful shutdown.

The good practice is to combine both methods.

Comment: I'd like to add a third quick (although slightly dirtier) option: instead of using your executable as your entrypoint, you can use a dedicated init process that spawns your executable.

[tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) is a good example of an entrypoint that can be used for this purpose: 

`ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "myserver", "--"]`.

This way PID 1 will be assigned to tini isntead of your executable.

This is useful if you don't want to ask your users to use `--init` and adding explicit signal handling to your app is too much work.

Answer (score 5):

I hope not being late, Nikscorp provides one of the possible reasons why your container could be no stopping, but this could happen in other cases like below:

- **Your `ENTRYPOINT` is a sheel script and you are not using Exec:** usually, when you run your container from a shell script, your container runs on a new process causing your container won't receive any signals, this can be solved using the exec command
- **Don't use Pipeline in your Exec entrypoint:** in some cases this can generate your application run in a subshell, which causes the no signals (SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL)
- **Using an incorrect form of Entrypoint:** the Entrypoint Form recommended is the exec form, like this one *(This happened to me and solved my problem)*

```
    ENTRYPOINT ["/app/bin/your-app", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

I based my answer on this [post](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86) and this [one](https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/)

Comment: "Not using Exec": specifically, in your shell script, put "exec " in front of your final command to hand off process control to that instead of having the shell sit in the background. Then it should receive signals directly.